Second derivative of a nondifferentiable function
Assume $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is continuous, but it is  not differentiable at $x_0$. Therefore, I define a special second derivative
$$
\frac{D^2 f}{D x^2}(x_0) = \frac{1}{2}\left[
\frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} (x_0^+) +  \frac{d^2 f}{dx^2} (x_0^-)
\right]
\tag{1}
$$
Then, if $x_0$ is the local minimum point of $f$, I want to show  $\frac{D^2 f}{D x^2}(x_0) \ge 0$.
I tried a few examples:
$$
y=|x|   ~~~~~~
y=\left\{
\begin{align}
&e^x -1    &x\ge 0\\
&x^{2n}   &x <0
\end{align}
\right.
\tag{2}
$$
They fit the above speculation. And from the graph of function, the above speculation also should be right. But I don't know how to prove it. May I have some help. Thanks.

If I understand your definition correctly then it makes only sense if $f$ is twice differentiable except possibly at $x_0$. Is that what you assume?

A counterexample (assuming that I understand your question correctly): $f(x) = \sqrt{1 + |x|}$, $x_0 = 0$.

@MartinR  Thanks, you are right. And I know the right way. Thanks again.

This doesn't work. Try
$$
f(x)= \begin{cases} -x(x+1), & x \leq 0\\ x(1-x), & x >0\end{cases}.
$$
According to your definition,
$$
\frac{D^2 f}{Dx^2}(0) = \frac 12 \left(f''(0^-) + f''(0^+)\right) = -2.
$$
In fact, there is really no point in searching for such a definition. A point of non-differentiability is an automatic candidate to local mimimum or maximum of a continuous function. You can come up with examples on minima and maxima for all possible combinations of sign for the right and left second derivative.
